# How do I position elements in a collapsed navbar (Boostrap 3)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to make a collapsed navbar with bootstrap. However, when I "open" the collapsed navbar, all of the elements are out of place, instead of stacked on top of each other. 
This is what it looks like:

[image: ..]

Here is my code for the navbar:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-65%);
  left: 65%;
  position: absolute;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  float: none;
}

.navbar-divider,
.navbar-nav .nav-item+.nav-item,
.navbar-nav .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 34em) {
  .navbar-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-nav .nav-item {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-divider,
  .navbar-nav .nav-item + .nav-item,
  .navbar-nav .nav-link + .nav-link {
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
}

/* Navbar collapse breakpoint */
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in {
    display:block !important;
  }
}

/* Navbar styling */
#navbar {

  height: 76.5px;
}

#navbarImg {
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  top: 5px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin: 0; 
  float: none; 
  text-align:center;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > .navbarButtonDiv > .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Bitter", serif;
  color: Black;
  font-size: 120%;
  top: 14.5px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > .navbarButtonDiv {
  margin-right: 50px;
  height: 76.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > .navbarButtonDiv:hover {
  background-color: #96D5FF;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > #navbarButtonDivHome {
  position: relative;
  width: 130px;
  bottom: 7px;
  right: 240px;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > #navbarButtonDivHome > a {
  left: 39px;
  top: 23px;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > #navbarButtonDivAbout {
  position: relative;
  width: 135px;
  bottom: 7px;
  right: 300px;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > #navbarButtonDivAbout > a {
  left: 41px;
  top: 23px;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > #navbarButtonDivLearn {
  position: relative;
  width: 135px;
  bottom: 7px;
  right: 360px;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > #navbarButtonDivLearn > a {
  left: 41px;
  top: 23px;
}

#navbarForm {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1150px;
  top: 18px;
}

#navbarFormSearch {
  width: 127%;
  font-family:"Bitter", serif;
}

#navbarFormSubmit {
  position: absolute;
  height: 38px;
  width: 46px;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 285px;
}

#navbarFormSubmitFa {
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

#navbar > #rightNavbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1600px;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > #navbarButtonDivLogIn {
  position: relative;
  width: 135px;
  bottom: 7px;
  right: 10px;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > #navbarButtonDivLogIn > a {
  left: 40px;
  top: 23px;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > #navbarButtonDivSignUp {
  position: relative;
  width: 135px;
  bottom: 7px;
  right: 65px;
}

#navbar > .nav > .nav-item > #navbarButtonDivSignUp > a {
  left: 35px;
  top: 23px;
}

#navbar > .nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 15.5%;
  top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- Home -->
        <li class="active nav-item">
          <div class="navbarButtonDiv" id="navbarButtonDivHome">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <!-- About -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="navbarButtonDiv" id="navbarButtonDivAbout">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <!-- Search -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="navbarButtonDiv" id="navbarButtonDivLearn">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#learn">Learn</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="navbarBrandImg">
          <img src="images/edufeLogo.png" id="navbarImg">
        </a>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <!-- Log In -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="navbarButtonDiv" id="navbarButtonDivLogIn">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#logIn">Log In</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <!-- Sign Up -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="navbarButtonDiv" id="navbarButtonDivSignUp">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#signUp">Sign Up</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Do you actually want the brand/logo to be inside the collapsed navigation or remain exposed above the collapsed nav?

Comment: I guess exposed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to go about this may be to just leave the `navbar-brand` in it's default placement (inside the `navbar-header`) and work around it with media queries. This way it's always exposed regardless of the viewport size.

Working Example:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:400,400italic,700);
 body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.navbar {
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom > .wrapper .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.navbar .nav.navbar-nav {
  font-size: 150%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 60px;
    transition: background 200ms linear;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background: #96D5FF;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse {
    margin: 20px 0 -20px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom" role="navigation">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x90/96D5FF/000?text=LOGO">
    </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Learn</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Log In</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="well">Yup</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Really helped! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.nav-item {
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the float lefts in your css that's causing them not to stack in mobile views. You could just apply the float to the list items on desktop size screens only using media queries, but bootstrap should take care of everything for you.

Have you looked at justified nav? Would be a lot easier than trying to control all the list items sizes on your own. What happens when you need to add a new menu item? It would become a maintenance nightmare.

https://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified